# google colab crashing due to ram limitations even after upgrading to colab pro

Tags: crash, google-colaboratory, ram, subscription

I purchased Google Colab Pro to increase my resources for RAM and GPU. However, after the purchase, my RAM resources still reflect as 12 GB. I was expecting at least a doubling of the RAM, but it didn't happen. When I run my project, it crashes due to insufficient RAM. I hope you can assist me with this issue, and I would appreciate it if you could help me to adjust my RAM allocation.

Thank you
Ryan

I purchased Google Colab Pro to increase my resources for RAM and GPU. However, after the purchase, my RAM resources still reflect as 12 GB. I was expecting at least a doubling of the RAM, but it didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the runtime type and select High-RAM.